# Translating C# "var" to VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I was previously working with a project in C# and now I'm basically doing the same project but in VB.net.

I don't know how to translate this to VB.net

```
foreach (var obj in objs)
```

The whole code is this:

```
public void BinaryFileSerialize(List<Animal> objs, string filePath)
{
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    try
    {
        fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        foreach (var obj in objs)
        {
            b.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Close();
    }

}
```

I tried doing it this way in VB.net:

```
For Each obj As var In objs
```

the whole code:

```
 Public Sub BinaryFileSerialize(ByVal objs As List(Of Animal), ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim fileStream As FileStream = Nothing
    Try
        fileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
        Dim b As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter
        For Each obj As var In objs
            b.Serialize(fileStream, obj)
        Next
    Finally
        If (Not (fileStream) Is Nothing) Then
            fileStream.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

But I'm getting error

> Type 'var' is not defined.

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: you can serialize the entire list instead of each object in it individually - in fact reading it back one `Animal` at a time might be problematic (never tried, but how would you know how many bytes to read for each object?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just skip the type altogether:

```
For Each obj In objs
```

You can read more about Local Type Inference in VB.NET on MSDN: [Local Type Inference (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub BinaryFileSerialize(objs As List(Of Animal), filePath As String)
    Dim fileStream As FileStream = Nothing
    Try
        fileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
        Dim b As New BinaryFormatter()
        For Each obj As Animal In objs
            b.Serialize(fileStream, obj)
        Next
    Finally
        If fileStream IsNot Nothing Then
            fileStream.Close()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below statement after putting `Option Infer On` as first line

```
For Each obj In objs
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have:
    `Option Explicit Off`

Then just change the loop to:
    `For Each obj In objs`